# Tips and tricks for faster developer loop Blazor Wasm NET7

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, blazor, blazor-webassembly

Due to the debugger being very slow to start in VS. We very often code by doing changes and then restart the app with `dotnet run` or `dotnet watch` in a cmd window. Now our project has grown and grown and quite much of code and .razor files in it. So every time we make a change and want to test, we do `CTRL+C` in the cmd window and then `dotnet run` again and wait about 30-60 seconds. In theory `dotnet watch` should work but it doesn't, a lot of "rude edits" errors and inconsistency so its usually just easier and safer to do a `dotnet run`. I read something about Optimize flag in `.csproj file` to make the build faster but not sure what it actually does. Does anyone have any tips and tricks for making this developer loop faster? Our project is a ASP.NET Core hosted Blazor WebAssembly project.

Comment: 2 points.  1)  I have a massive site, and it takes about 20 seconds to rebuild. You may want to consider upgrading your computer, in particular the CPU. 2) Only modified Proejcts are rebuilt.  You may want to consider putting finished code in a Razor class library and link to it in your site's main project, so that only code still in development needs to recompile every run.

Comment: @Bennyboy1973 suggestion of splitting you site out into separate logical libraries should improve the time.  Personally I develop and test most of my code on Blazor Server or XUnit for backend stuff - I have both Server and WASM deployments for projects. - so only final test on WASM.  Almost everything you write should work on both.